# Forward emails from a specifc sender in outlook via python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, office-automation

i try the below code but the attribute error is driving me crazy !, any thing after message. gets me an attribute error, wtv prop. i use. i end up with attribute error.

```
AttributeError: <unknown>.Sender
```

Code:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the inbox
messages = inbox.Items

sender_email = "TDC@AE.Roco.COM"
recipient_email = "simple.invoice@net"

for message in messages:
    if message.Sender.Address == sender_email:
        new_mail = message.Forward()
        new_mail.Recipients.Add(recipient_email)
        for attachment in message.Attachments:
            new_mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
        new_mail.Save()
```

Based on given answers:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
accounts = mapi.Folders

query = '@SQL="urn:schemas:httpmail:from" = ' + "'TDC@AE.Roco.COM'" + ' AND "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" = ' + "'1'"
print(query)

try:
    items = inbox.Items.Restrict(query)
    print(f'Number of items found : {items.count}')


    def check_subfolders(folder):
        items = folder.Items.Restrict(query)
        if items.count > 0:
            print(f'{items.count} emails found in {folder.name}')
        for subfolder in folder.Folders:
            check_subfolders(subfolder)


    check_subfolders(inbox)
    for folder in mapi.Folders:
        items = folder.Items.Restrict(query)
        if items.count > 0:
            print(f'{items.count} emails found in {folder.name}')
    for item in items:
        mail = item.Forward()
        mail.Recipients.Add("simple.invoice@net")
        mail.Subject = "Fwd: " + item.Subject
        mail.Body = "Please find the forwarded message with attachments below:\n\n" + item.Body
        mail.Save()
except Exception as e:
    print(f'An error occurred: {e}')
```

Now I have no errors but the result returns zero, although I have mails from that specified sender!

Answer (score 1):

Not all Outlook items provide the `Sender` property. Outlook **folders may contains different kind of items** - notes, calendar items, mail items, document items and etc. So, it makes sense to make sure that you deal with a mail item, for example, you could check the [MessageClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.messageclass) property.

Instead of iterating over all items in Outlook:

```
for message in messages:
    if message.Sender.Address == sender_email:
```

Use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. They allow getting items that correspond to the search criteria, so you can iterate over them without checking a property each time. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Use the following search criteria to get items from the specified email address:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:senderemail" & Chr(34) _ 
& " = 'eugene@astafiev.com'"
```

---

If you need to send an item from a specific sender, you can use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. Note, the other account should be configured in Outlook. For example, a sample in VBA shows how to use it:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

Another approach is to use the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property which returns or sets a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. In that case the other user should have permissions to send on behalf of another person in Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

`Sender` property is only exposed by the `MailItem` object, but you can also have `ReportItem` and `MeetingItem` objects in the Inbox folder. You need to check first that `Class` property == 43 (which is `olMail`)

Also, do not loop through all items in a folder - use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` with a query like `[SenderEmailAddress] = 'TDC@AE.Roco.COM'`

Answer (score 1):

Quick Example

```
import win32com.client

def outlook_emails(Inbox):
    Filter_sender = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail"" " \
                    "ci_phrasematch 'TDC@AE.Roco.COM'"

    items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter_sender)
    print(items.Count)

    for i in reversed(range(items.Count, 0, -1)):
        if items[i].Class == 43:
            print(items[i].Subject)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch(
        "outlook.Application").GetNamespace(
        "MAPI"
    )

    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    outlook_emails(inbox)
```

[@SQL=""urn:schemas:httpmail:fromemail"" ci_phrasematch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Search-and-Filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison)